# "Several suggestions have been offered for adoption by the panel", who will adopt the suggestions?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence

I have a sentence

> Several suggestions have been offered for adoption by the panel.

My question is, is the panel supposed to adopt the suggestions, or the panel offered those suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase is ambiguous in English.  Consider re-wording:

> "The panel has offered several suggestions for adoption."
>
> "Several suggestions have been offered for the panel to adopt."

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on context.

The same sentence could be used to mean both "suggestions that the panel should adopt" or "suggestions the panel has made for adoption by someone else". It does read awkwardly for the second one which would look better as "Several suggestions have been made by the panel for adoption."

Was there a particular context you saw/read this in?

Comment: I don't have context. I'm learning English and found this sentence. Thanks for the answer.